# how to write down something to console before getting user input in C?

Tags: c, eclipse, input, console

I'm simply trying to write down something to console using C language before getting user input, but it always asks for input then when I press enter it print what I wanted to print before getting user input.
I'm using Eclipse IDE (version 2020 -09) and my compiler is Cygwin.
this is how I'm to trying to accomplish that:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    printf("please enter your name: ");
        char a[3];
        gets(a);
        return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Output is usually buffered by default.

You can flush the output buffer explicitly by calling `fflush(stdout)` after `printf()`, eg:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("please enter your name: ");
    fflush(stdout); // <-- here
    char a[3];
    gets(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Or, you can include `\n` in the output, eg:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("please enter your name: \n");
    char a[3];
    gets(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding the first solution worked so perfectly but I don't know why the second one is not working do you think it's because of my compiler? or I missed a package while installing? (I'm using Cygwin).